# Django Login Incorrect password showing for correct password

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication

I am making a login form and using Django 1.8 Python 3.5

But I am getting Incorrect password for valid username and password what should I do ?

I have made a simple login form but am not able to figure out the error , please help

This is my `login/forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from mainpage.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    login,
    logout,
    get_user_model,
)

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
        username=forms.CharField(max_length=40)
        password=forms.CharField(max_length=40,widget=forms.PasswordInput)


        def clean(self,*args,**kwargs):
            username=self.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password=self.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user_qs = User.objects.filter(username=username)
            if user_qs.count() == 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError("The user does not exist")
            else:
                if username and password:
                     user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

                     if not user:
                        raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password")
                     if not user.is_active:
                         raise forms.ValidationError("This user is no longer active")
            return super(UserLoginForm,self).clean(*args,**kwargs)
```

This is my `login/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import UserLoginForm
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_loginwa
from django.contrib.auth import (

    authenticate,
    logout,
    get_user_model,

)
def login_view(request):
    form1=UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    if form1.is_valid():
        username=form1.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password=form1.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        auth_loginwa(request,user)
        if(request.user.is_authenticated()):
            return redirect("home2")
    context= {
        "form1": form1,
    }
    return render(request, "login.html",context)
```

This is my `mainpage/models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**As asked in comments**

this is  my **mainpage/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User
admin.site.register(User)
```

these are images for my different users

superuser vaibhav2(created using command python manage.py create superuser)[Has encrypted password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL6E4.jpg) also the login of it get s successful

user asd create manually [(No encrypted password see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwVRV.jpg)

https://imgur.com/EOewk41

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you're doing much more work than you need. `authenticate` already checks that the user exists as well as verifying the password, so there's no point in the separate User query; also you really don't need to call authenticate both in the form and the view.

Comment: Re your actual problem, how did you create the user originally?

Comment: Going to the localhost:8000/admin then adding a user manually

Comment: Hmm but how is the admin for that User model defined? Are you subclassing django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin so that it knows to hash the password?

Comment: I have edited the question,Also I think you have figured out the problem the users for which the password is encrypted work like charm but those which have been created manually don't work

Comment: But if I add users using signup form which I have created the password goes in unencrypted what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom ModelAdmin class that subclasses the built-in one.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Sorry but I am a newbie

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I have shown you the code you need to use.

Comment: No. This is the replacement for the admin code you showed already.

Comment: Also in login/views.py do I  need to do form1=CustomUserAdmin(request.POST or NONE) ???

Comment: Ok so just add your this code to mainpage/admin.py that is all ?

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Roseman is right. You need to point your defined model to the UserAdmin to enable encryption. Add the below snippet to your `admin.py` file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```